# How to see if a NSUserdefaults is nil or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Well I dont know if my title is well drafted but I will try to explain whats my problem, I want to save a NSDate for an IndexPath in NSUserDefaults, this happens when `viewWillDisappear` but its crashing, its saving correctly because when I reopen the DatePicker loads the date I want but still crash when saving a date at the UserDefaults
So heres my code so you can see whats going on....

I read if the NSUserDefaults is nil or not so I can load the DatePicker:

```
    NSArray *indexParams = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:@"indexpath"];
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexParams[1]
                                              inSection:indexParams[0]];

self.notificationDate = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:@"date"];
NSDate *date = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIndexPath.row]];

if(date){
    [self.NotSwith setOn:YES];
    self.DatePicker.date = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIndexPath.row]];



}else{
    [self.NotSwith setOn:NO];


    }
```

When I want to save the date in `viewWillDisappear` its when the crash happens:

```
NSArray *indexParams = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:@"indexpath"];
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexParams[1]
                                              inSection:indexParams[0]];

NSDate *date = [self.userdefaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIndexPath.row]];

if(date){
//    [self.userdefaults synchronize];


}

else{
    [self.userdefaults setObject:self.DatePicker.date forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIndexPath.row]];
    [self.userdefaults synchronize];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local];


}
```

But the info its saved successfully and the date picker loads the date in relaunch.

crash log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

So hope I explained well, Thanks!

Setting the indexpath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



    NSNumber *section = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *rows = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];

    [self.userdefaults setObject:@[section, rows] forKey:@"indexpath"];
}
```

Comment: Lot's of scary-looking code for an un-scary-sounding job.  Can you describe the functional goal? Why are index paths involved?  Do you just want a date saved or other objects?

Comment: Exactly what line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: The date is saved according to the indexpath of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath so when you exit and reopen you can see when do you set the datePicker. This datepicker is show for the tableview row selected, I hope I explain, and I would be grateful if you can explain me why its a scary-looking code, Im starting so Im doing what I can, Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you need to abstract your data model more - If the date is associated with a piece of data in the table, then that is how you should store it - tableviews and date pickers are just things that display your data and shouldn't be incorporated into the underlying data storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to save both the selected index path and a date.  Saving a date in NSUserDefaults is easy.

```
// no need to keep a property on self for user defaults.  you don't need to keep
// that around.  just a stack variable will work.
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

[defaults setObject:date forKey:@"myDate"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Get it back later on this way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *date = [defaults objectForKey:@"myDate"];

// if nothing has been stored using that key then objectForKey will return nil
if (date) {
    // it's there!
} else {
    // it's not there
}
```

Storing an index path is a little more tricky, but this will work:

```
// wrap your row and section in NSNumbers, wrap those in an array for brevity
NSNumber *section = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myIndexPath.section]; 
NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myIndexPath.row];

[defaults setObject:@[section, row] forKey:@"myIndexPath"];  // then synchronize

// naturally, when you get it later, you can check for nil again, and,
// if it's not nil, to rebuild the index path...

NSArray *indexParams = [defaults objectForKey:@"myIndexPath"];
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexParams[1]
                                              inSection:indexParams[0]];
```

The key is what isn't in this answer: no NSData, no NSKeyedArchiver, no string manipulation to build an index path representation.  Best of luck.

Comment: It works in the first launch but now crashes in the second launch(same crash log) and is not saving... Can you help me please? thanks!

Comment: Can you set an exception breakpoint (breakpoints pane on the left, hit the plus sign on the bottom).  Then, please post current code, especially where crash occurs).

Comment: When I follow the flow of the application with the breakpoints as I tell you the first launch is ok but in the second one is not saving the date and crashing after viewWillDisappear. I updated the code and added when setting the indexpath